# Multi-platform apps with SwiftUI previews

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'd like to render iOS and macOS SwiftUI previews simultaneously, to see how code changes affect each platform.

Each platform has its own target, and the previews look like this:

```swift
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
        MyView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation)"))
        #else
        MyView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Mac"))
        #endif
    }
}
```

... but, you have to switch schemes to preview the targeted platform.

Is there a way to preview iOS and macOS at the same time?

Comment: I don't believe so. Unless your target is explicitly multi-platform, you can only render previews for an individual target. I could be wrong, however.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well.